# Is Statistics::Descriptive similar to using Statistics::R module( in a PERL Script)?

Tags: perl, perl-module

I think Statistics::Descriptive does not call R language module, whereas the Statistics::R does.

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Statistics::Descriptive` is a simple pure-Perl module offering basic functionality for stats. You can read the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/Statistics%3a%3aDescriptive) or the [source code](https://metacpan.org/source/SHLOMIF/Statistics-Descriptive-3.0605/lib/Statistics/Descriptive.pm) to answer the question yourself: Statistics::Descriptive does not use R under the hood. Who would have thought that you could do statistical ananlysis with languages other than R?

The `Statistics::Descriptive` and `Statistics::R` modules are very different: Whereas `S::D` offers Perl objects representing data collections which you can call various methods on, the `S::R` is just a convenient wrapper around an R [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REPL), and requires you to write snippets of R code.